# Using the following code I am unable to raise list view using simplecursoradaptor

Tags: java, android

After having made a lots of search for bring out a listview from sqlite database table using the following code I have no other go other than to get solved by known circles. The line where I raise the simplecursoradapter is causing the problem it seems and my apps stops. There is no other error in the code. If I comment the line simplecursoradapter, this eror doesnt come but ofcourse there is no listview.

```
    Cursor c= vivzHelper.getAllRows();    
    String[] from = new String[]{ vivzHelper.NAME};    
    int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};    
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,c,from,to,0);    
    ListView thislist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);    
    thislist.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);    


    public Cursor getAllRows( ) {
    String where = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = { VivzHelper.UID,VivzHelper.NAME};
    Cursor c = db.query(VivzHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
    }
```

Comment: app stops. crash!. check the stacktrace and post the same here

Comment: Are you not using custom_row.xml for single row of xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following changes, you will have a list view displayed, create a new xml file with name of your choice. You need only one item in your list view as per your requirement hence, you can give a text view to the new xml file as shown below:

// Defining single row of list view:
custom_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/custom_listView"
        android:orientation="horizontal">




        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Task1"
           android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity do this, define the custom  row and for your to array specify the custom row:

```
Cursor c= vivzHelper.getAllRows();    
    String[] from = new String[]{ vivzHelper.NAME};    
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textView}; // textView of custom row.   
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
 cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.cutsom_row, c, from, to, 0);    
    ListView thislist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);    
    thislist.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);    


    public Cursor getAllRows( ) {
    String where = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = { VivzHelper.UID,VivzHelper.NAME};
    Cursor c = db.query(VivzHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
    }
```

This must be sufficient to display your list view, let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73356/discussion-on-answer-by-kesh1234-using-the-following-code-i-am-unable-to-raise-l).